# Should I run "apolloServer.executeOperation" on Next's "getServerSideProps"?

Tags: node.js, graphql, next.js, apollo

I'm trying to figure out the best way of running GraphQL queries in the `getServerSideProps` of a Next.js app.

Since the GraphQL server is running on the same Next.js instance, the obvious solution is to run `apolloServer.executeOperation()` on the `getServerSideProps` function of my pages.

However, I'm worried about this solution because:

1. [The documentation of `executeOperation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/testing/testing/#executeoperation) describes it as an integration tests function. It literally says "*The executeOperation method provides a single hook to run operations through the request pipeline, enabling the most thorough tests possible without starting up an HTTP server.*". But it doesn't say it should only be used for testing.
2. Pretty much all online Guides I find online about running GraphQL on Next.js says I should use an apollo client ([Example](https://medium.com/@zhamdi/server-side-rendering-ssr-using-apollo-and-next-js-ac0b2e3ea461)). However, running an Apollo Client on the same server as my GraphQL server seems like an obvious unnecessary overhead.

Which leads me to think I maybe missing something obvious.

Is it OK to call `apolloServer.executeOperation` on my Next.js `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: I ran into the same issue as you (although using a Relay client with Apollo server backend). I found executeOperation was hard to plug my query directly into. This was likely since I was using Relay for client queries (so the network layer was helpful to abstract that away).  Relay had a specific library for SSR (https://github.com/relay-tools/react-relay-network-modern-ssr) which allowed a local network request *or* a direct graphql-js call to execute the query on my server (both still creating a "client"). The resulting cache could be serialized and plugged into the client easily.

Answer (score 0):

We run a basic async fetch on the `getStaticProps`, in our Next app, a formatted response gets passed to the `Home` component and used to setup the redux store.

I imagine that if you were to do a graphql request you would need to init the graphql client before you can use it - which happens later in the call chain for us, and i imagine you. You could maybe do your GQL client setup server side and pass the object by props to Home, but doesn't seem like thats the intended use.

I'd say if you need to server side request with GQL, create a client getServerSideProps and close it after your request, don't see much of an issue with that.